# Angular 6 Dynamic Routing Table From Database

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angular, angular6

I want to define the routing table in app.routing.ts from the database. The data for the routing file will be retrieved from the table in the database on the initialization of the project.

I have tried the same by making an HTTP Get call from app.component.ts and adding the routes from the same file into routes configure.

It doesn't give the error when I add the route after making the database call and adding the same. When I route the same, It gives the me an error that no routes are available.

Please help me out the same. Any kind of help is appreciated

I have tried to develop the prototype for the same.

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  routes: Routes = [];
  data: any;
  loaded: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      //routes.push(data);
      if (!this.loaded) {
        let routerConfig = this.router.config;
        //routerConfig.unshift(data[0]);
        // routerConfig[0]._loadedConfig.routes[0].children.unshift({
        //   path: `lazy`,
        //   loadChildren: 'app/lazy.module#LazyModule'
        // });
        // console.log('/lazy route (Portal child) added', 
         routerConfig);
        //this.router.resetConfig(routerConfig);
        let compName = data[0].component;
        let comp: any = 
        (<any>AppModule).__annotations__[0].declarations.find(comp => 
        {
           return comp.name === compName;
        });
        routerConfig.unshift({path: 'login', component: 
        mapping[comp]})

        this.router.resetConfig(routerConfig);
        this.loaded = true;
      }
    });
  }

  public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1g16wr");
  }
}
```

//app.routing.ts

```js
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { AddUserComponent } from "./add-user/add-user.component";
import { ListUserComponent } from "./list-user/list-user.component";
import { EditUserComponent } from "./edit-user/edit-user.component";
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const routes: Routes = [];



// function f(){
//   console.log(this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mfh63"));
// }

// f();

// const routes: Routes = [
//   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
//   { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent },
//   { path: 'list-user', component: ListUserComponent },
//   { path: 'edit-user', component: EditUserComponent },
//   { path: '*', component: LoginComponent }
// ];


//   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
//   { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent },
//   { path: 'list-user', component: ListUserComponent },
//   { path: 'edit-user', component: EditUserComponent },
//   { path: '*', component: LoginComponent }
// ];

// export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
//   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
//     console.log('second');
//     this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
//       let testData = data;
//       routes.push(testData);
//       console.log(routes);
//     });

//   }
//   ngOnInit() {
//     console.log('first');
//   }

//   public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
//     return this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mfh63");
//   }
// }

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

app.component.html

```js
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { AddUserComponent } from "./add-user/add-user.component";
import { ListUserComponent } from "./list-user/list-user.component";
import { EditUserComponent } from "./edit-user/edit-user.component";
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
const routes: Routes = [];



// function f(){
//   console.log(this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mfh63"));
// }

// f();

// const routes: Routes = [
//   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
//   { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent },
//   { path: 'list-user', component: ListUserComponent },
//   { path: 'edit-user', component: EditUserComponent },
//   { path: '*', component: LoginComponent }
// ];


//   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
//   { path: 'add-user', component: AddUserComponent },
//   { path: 'list-user', component: ListUserComponent },
//   { path: 'edit-user', component: EditUserComponent },
//   { path: '*', component: LoginComponent }
// ];

// export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
//   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
//     console.log('second');
//     this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
//       let testData = data;
//       routes.push(testData);
//       console.log(routes);
//     });

//   }
//   ngOnInit() {
//     console.log('first');
//   }

//   public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
//     return this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mfh63");
//   }
// }

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

it shows that the specific route is not found. If anything specific is needed, please reply I will upload you the project.

Comment: Check out solution here https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/angular-ng-10-create-update-route-at-runtime.html